# how do I assign\convert\cast any type object to specific type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have object of type any and I assign object of type myResponse like below

```
    public obj: any;
    public set Result() {
        obj = myResponse;
    }
```

I have another function where I want to cast any type to my specific type like below

```
public myFunction(){
    let x: MyResponse = (MyResponse) obj;
    conosle.log(x.somePropoerty);
}
```

I have tried different methods which I got online like angular brackets for casting, Object.assign but it did not work.

MyResponse class is like below

```
export class MyResponse{
    public property1: string;
    public property2: number;
    //some other code
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Is `MyResponse` a class or an interface? How it is defined? Does the content of `obj` at least match the same interface? Explain.

Comment: MyResponse is class...class has some property..Yes content obj should match the same class...As I assigned instance of same class to obj and now I am trying to convert it back to MyResponse class.

Comment: So how do you usually get a class instance from some provided data? Pretty sure you do that on a regular basis, and then why would you think this would be any different. So think! What does `new Date(0)` actually do?

Comment: `obj = myResponse;` should be `this.obj = myResponse  as MyResponse;`

Comment: Have you tried this let x: MyResponse  = Object.assign({},myResponse ) and x['someProperty'] to get the value

Comment: Do you still have problems with your code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no casting in TypeScript, only type assertions. You can assert that `obj` is of type `MyResponse` by doing:

```
let x: MyResponse = obj as MyResponse;
```

Do note that this is for compile-time checking only. If your `obj` is not a `MyResponse` instance at runtime then this won't work.

Comment: Well yes I tried this but When I try to access property inside MyReponse..it shows as undefined...I am sure property has values....

Comment: Is `obj` an instance of `MyResponse` at runtime? Post the definition for `MyResponse`.

Comment: yes obj is instance of MyReponse at runtime.....I have posted definition of MyResponse class..

Answer (score 0):

Casting (Microsoft call it **Type assertions**) in TypeScript can be done in two ways.

Let's say we got following object definition:

```
class MyClass {
    public someMethod:void() {
         console.log("method invoked");
    }
    public static staticMethod(object: MyClass) {
         console.log("static method");
         object.someMethod();
    }
}
```

The first way of casting is very similar to Java style. You need to use `<>` signs.

```
let someVariable: any = new MyClass();
someVariable.someMethod(); //won't compile
MyClass.staticMethod(someVariable); //won't compile

(<MyClass> someVariable).someMethod(); //will compile
MyClass.staticMethod(<MyClass> someVariable); //will compile
```

Second way is as @Saravana showed (using `as` keyword):

```
//all below lines compiles
let someVariable: any = new MyClass();
let another: MyClass = someVariable as MyClass;
(someVariable as MyClass).someMethod(); 

MyClass.staticMethod(someVariable as MyClass);
```

Check out this link for more informations: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Answer (score 0):

To properly cast into "Type", you basically need to change the prototype of the object. 
That can be done by creating a new instance using the Constructor function, then copying your existing properties.

Otherwise type assertion will only provide a compile-time check! During runtime the "someMethod" will be undefined